# Getting the value of an input box with jquery and then applying a style

Tags: jquery

I want to be able to get the value of the input box rendered below

```
<td>
    <input type="hidden" name="IsValidatedSwitch" class="super" value="Assigned">
</td>
```

Here is my jquery. All I get back for result is an empty string. The commented line
works well for result2.

What am I doing wrong in getting the value of result?

```
$('#Play').click(function () {          
    $("table tbody tr").each(function () {
        row = $(this).closest("tr");
        //var result2 = $(row).find("td div.super").text();
        var result = $(row).find("input IsvalidatedSwitch").text();
        if (result == "Assigned") {                    
            $(row).addClass("assignCb");
        }
    });
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: You can't just write random stuff and then ask us to fix it. Have you even read the jQuery documentation?

Comment: First, it's better to have a better selector for the table. like a class or id. Second, you are using a wrong format of each function. Look at here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: Siderite - who is writing random stuff? what do you mean by that? No I have not read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access input element values with [**`val()`**](http://api.jquery.com/val/) instead of `text()`.

If there are multiple input elements, do:

```
var result = $(row).find("input[name=IsvalidatedSwitch]").val();
```

Otherwise, you can simply do:

```
var result = $(row).find("input").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

I see your selection $('table tbody tr') returns the rows of table. So inside .each() you must have the row of table. I can't find the  significance of .closest('tr'). Could you please look at this and try what Rick Hitchcock suggested ? Let us know for any queries.